# App rejection by apple on facebook login

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I am using login with facebook in my app and getting username and profile pic from facebook. I have tested and it is working fine at my end, but apple has rejected it two times. I dont find any error at my end .

This is error by apple team:-
" We still found that your app exhibited one or more bugs, when reviewed on iPad Air running iOS 7.1 and an iPhone 5s running iOS 7.1, on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks, which is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.
Specifically, when we tap login to Facebook we get message say it wants to connect and when we tap ok it does not advance and connect with Facebook. "

Here is my Code

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 {
UIWindow *window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.window = window;

self.login=[[ViewController alloc]init];
_nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.login];



self.window.rootViewController = _nav;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
// Override point for customization after application launch.

// Whenever a person opens the app, check for a cached session
if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded) {
    NSLog(@"Found a cached session");
    // If there's one, just open the session silently, without showing the user the login UI
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"basic_info", @"email", @"user_likes"]
                                       allowLoginUI:NO
                                  completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
                                      // Handler for session state changes
                                      // This method will be called EACH time the session state changes,
                                      // also for intermediate states and NOT just when the session open
                                      [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];

                                      switch (state) {
                                          case FBSessionStateOpen:
                                              [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {
                                                  if (error) {

                                                      NSLog(@"error:%@",error);


                                                  }
                                                  else
                                                  {
                                                      // retrive user's details at here as shown below


                                                      NSUserDefaults *storeData=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                                                      [storeData setObject:user.id forKey:@"user_id"];
                                                      [storeData setObject:user.name forKey:@"name"];

                                                  }
                                              }];
                                              break;

                                          case FBSessionStateClosed:
                                          case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
                                              [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
                                              break;

                                          default:
                                              break;
                                      }



                                  }];

    // If there's no cached session, we will show a login button
} else {
    //UIButton *loginButton = [self.login loginButton];
    //[loginButton setTitle:@"Log in with Facebook" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
return YES;


  }

  - (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
 {
// Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
// Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
  }

 - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
// Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
// If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
 }

 - (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
 {
// Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}


 // This method will handle ALL the session state changes in the app
 - (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session state:(FBSessionState) state error:(NSError *)error
 {
// If the session was opened successfully
if (!error && state == FBSessionStateOpen){
    NSLog(@"Session opened");
    // Show the user the logged-in UI
    [self userLoggedIn];
    return;
}
if (state == FBSessionStateClosed || state == FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed){
    // If the session is closed
    NSLog(@"Session closed");
    // Show the user the logged-out UI
    [self userLoggedOut];
}

// Handle errors
if (error){
    NSLog(@"Error");
    NSString *alertText;
    NSString *alertTitle;
    // If the error requires people using an app to make an action outside of the app in order to recover
    if ([FBErrorUtility shouldNotifyUserForError:error] == YES){
        alertTitle = @"Something went wrong";
        alertText = [FBErrorUtility userMessageForError:error];
        [self showMessage:alertText withTitle:alertTitle];
    } else {

        // If the user cancelled login, do nothing
        if ([FBErrorUtility errorCategoryForError:error] == FBErrorCategoryUserCancelled) {
            NSLog(@"User cancelled login");

            // Handle session closures that happen outside of the app
        } else if ([FBErrorUtility errorCategoryForError:error] == FBErrorCategoryAuthenticationReopenSession){
            alertTitle = @"Session Error";
            alertText = @"Your current session is no longer valid. Please log in again.";
            [self showMessage:alertText withTitle:alertTitle];

            // For simplicity, here we just show a generic message for all other errors
            // You can learn how to handle other errors using our guide: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
        } else {
            //Get more error information from the error
            NSDictionary *errorInformation = [[[error.userInfo objectForKey:@"com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey"] objectForKey:@"body"] objectForKey:@"error"];

            // Show the user an error message
            alertTitle = @"Something went wrong";
            alertText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Please retry. \n\n If the problem persists contact us and mention this error code: %@", [errorInformation objectForKey:@"message"]];
            [self showMessage:alertText withTitle:alertTitle];
        }
    }
    // Clear this token
    [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
    // Show the user the logged-out UI
    [self userLoggedOut];
}
  }

// Show the user the logged-out UI
- (void)userLoggedOut
 {
// Set the button title as "Log in with Facebook"
// UIButton *loginButton = [self.login loginButton];
//[loginButton setTitle:@"Log in with Facebook" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

// Confirm logout message
      //[self showMessage:@"You're now logged out" withTitle:@""];
  }

 // Show the user the logged-in UI
- (void)userLoggedIn
 {
// Set the button title as "Log out"
// UIButton *loginButton = self.login.loginButton;
//[loginButton setTitle:@"Log out" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

     FrontViewController *v=[[FrontViewController alloc]init];
RearViewController *rearViewController = [[RearViewController alloc] init];

UINavigationController *frontNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:v];
UINavigationController *rearNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rearViewController];


SWRevealViewController *revealController = [[SWRevealViewController alloc] initWithRearViewController:rearNavigationController frontViewController:frontNavigationController];
revealController.delegate = self;


[self.nav pushViewController:revealController animated:YES];



[self showMessage:@"You're now logged in" withTitle:@"Welcome!"];

  }

  // Show an alert message
  - (void)showMessage:(NSString *)text withTitle:(NSString *)title
  {
[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                            message:text
                           delegate:self
                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK!"
                  otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
 }

   // During the Facebook login flow, your app passes control to the Facebook iOS app or Facebook in a mobile browser.
  // After authentication, your app will be called back with the session information.
  // Override application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation to call the FBsession object that handles the incoming URL

     - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
        openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
     annotation:(id)annotation
 {
  return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{

// Handle the user leaving the app while the Facebook login dialog is being shown
// For example: when the user presses the iOS "home" button while the login dialog is active
   [FBAppCall handleDidBecomeActive];
}
```

In My View Controller

```
  - (IBAction)buttonTouched:(id)sender
 {
  // If the session state is any of the two "open" states when the button is clicked
  if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpen
    || FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended) {

    // Close the session and remove the access token from the cache
    // The session state handler (in the app delegate) will be called automatically
    [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];

    // If the session state is not any of the two "open" states when the button is clicked
} else {
    // Open a session showing the user the login UI
    // You must ALWAYS ask for basic_info permissions when opening a session
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"basic_info", @"email", @"user_likes"]
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
                                  completionHandler:
     ^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {

         // Retrieve the app delegate
         AppDelegate* appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
         // Call the app delegate's sessionStateChanged:state:error method to handle session state changes
         [appDelegate sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];

         switch (state) {
             case FBSessionStateOpen:
                 [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {
                     if (error) {

                         NSLog(@"error:%@",error);


                     }
                     else
                     {
                         // retrive user's details at here as shown below
                         NSLog(@"FB user first name:%@",user.first_name);



                             NSUserDefaults *storeData=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                            [storeData setObject:user.id forKey:@"user_id"];
                            [storeData setObject:user.name forKey:@"name"];

                     }


                 }];
                 break;

             case FBSessionStateClosed:
             case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
                 [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
                 break;

             default:
                 break;
         }

     }];
}
```

}

Comment: when you run your app and tap login to Facebook and then tap connect, does it continue and login, or does it stop there?

Comment: when i do, it continue with facebook and i am able to get inside the app and share pic to my facebook.

Comment: Have you tried deleting your test version and reinstalling fresh to see if you can replicate their issue?

Comment: What happens if you try with the connection disabled?

Comment: Try also in the SIM, using 64 bit configuration

Comment: @Logan I have send the IPA file to client , it is also working on his device.

Comment: Just a though, are you allowing for all possible eventualities as far as Facebook Authentication is concerned, by this i mean. 1. The user doesn't have Facebook App installed. 2. user doesn't have Facebook credentials set up in settings?

Answer (score 1):

Is your app on developer.facebook.com public and available for all users?

Status should look like this:
[image: Facebook app satus]

In other case if your app has status `Developer Mode` then other users can't authorise by Facebook.

Comment: Yes, It is public and available to all users

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same issue. Although it's a Flutter app, but the use-case is the same.

On my end, everything works as expected

Fb app has iOS and Bundle ID set correctly

FB app is public

But the Apple review team still rejects it. I asked for more Screenshots, which they provided, AND the screenshots clearly show the "continue" dialog of the FB-popup. So I don't understand why they rejected it.